# Using multiple workspace environments ArcGIS Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, error-000732

I have 1 folder with shapefiles and a geodatebase. I'm trying to export the shapefiles and geodatebase feature datasets but I need to reference 2 Workspace Environments in order for the script to read both destinations.

Error Message:
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 68, in    File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 1811, in FeatureClassToGeodatabase     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset 'ODORANT TEST POINTS.shp';COMPONENTS.shp;FARM_TAPS.shp;LINE_MARKERS.shp;MAIN_LINES.shp;METERS.shp;SERVICE_LINES.shp;STATIONS.shp does not exist or is not supported

```
  # Read (2) Workspace environments 
  67. for ws in workspaces:
  68.     arcpy.env.workspace = ws
```

Code:

```
# Import modules
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Set environment settings
workspaces = [
    'M:/EIS_DRAFTS/EIS/Company SHP Files'
    'M:/EIS_DRAFTS/EIS/Company SHP Files/Company UPDM.gdb'
]

# Set local variables
in_dataset_P_Integrity = ['P_Anomaly', 'P_AnomalyGroup',
'P_ConsequenceSegment',
'P_ControlPoint',
'P_CouldAffectSegment',
'P_DASurveyReadings',
'P_DocumentPoint',
'P_DOTClass',
'P_Elevation',
'P_GasOdorReport',
'P_HighConsequenceArea',
'P_ILIGroundRefMarkers',
'P_ILIInspectionRange',
'P_ILISurveyGroup',
'P_ILISurveyReadings',
'P_InlineInspection',
'P_InspectionNote',
'P_InspectionRange',
'P_LeakSurvey_AreaSurvey',
'P_LeakSurvey_Atmosphere',
'P_LeakSurvey_BareSteel',
'P_LeakSurvey_Business',
'P_LeakSurvey_CastIron',
'P_MAOPCalcRange',
'P_OperatingPressureRange',
'P_PipeCrossing',
'P_PipeExposure',
'P_ServiceInterruptionEvent',
'P_StationSeries',
'P_TestPressureRange']

in_dataset_P_PipeSystem = ['P_CompressorStation', 'P_ControllableFitting',
'P_CPAnode',
'P_CPBondJunction',
'P_CPBondWire',
'P_CPRectifier',
'P_CPRectifierCable',
'P_CPTestPoint',
'P_DehydrationEquip',
'P_Drip',
'P_ExcessFlowValve',
'P_GasLamp',
'P_GatheringFieldPipe',
'P_LineHeater',
'P_MeterSetting',
'P_NonControllableFitting',
'P_Odorizer',
'P_PigStructure',
'P_Pipes',
'P_PipeSystem_Net_Junctions',
'P_PressureMonitoringDevice',
'P_PumpStation',
'P_RegulatorStation',
'P_ReliefValve',
'P_RiverCrossing',
'P_RuralTap',
'P_Scrubber',
'P_Service',
'P_Strainer',
'P_Tank',
'P_TownBorderStation',
'P_Valve',
'P_Well']

in_dataset_P_EverythingElse = ['ODORANT TEST POINTS.shp', 
'COMPONENTS.shp',
'FARM_TAPS.shp',
'LINE_MARKERS.shp',
'MAIN_LINES.shp',
'METERS.shp',
'SERVICE_LINES.shp',
'STATIONS.shp']

out_dataset_P_Integrity = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Company.gdb/P_Integrity'
out_dataset_P_PipeSystem = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Company.gdb/P_PipeSystem'
out_dataset_P_EverythingElse = 'C:/EnterpriseFolder/Company.gdb'

try:
    for ws in workspaces:
        arcpy.env.workspace = ws
        # Use ListFeatureClasses to generate a list of inputs
        for infc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

        arcpy.env.outputMFlag = "Disabled"
        arcpy.env.outputZFlag = "Disabled"

        #Execute FeatureClassToGeodatabase
        arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(in_dataset_P_Integrity,out_dataset_P_Integrity)
```

Comment: "I feel like this piece isn't searching correctly" - what is it doing or not doing exactly?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Midavalo The script isn't searching the 2 workspace environments for the defined shapefiles and feature datasets listed in my #Set local variables.                   
Error Message Reads: does not exist or is not supported

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your entire error message text including any line numbers

Comment: Remove the spaces from your folder/workspace names and re-test (you'll need to actually rename them, not just change them in python).  You could test on a copy without spaces if you can't rename those folders.

Comment: @Midavalo The spaces have been removed on the folders but it's still unable to read the 2 workspace environment directory paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error appears to be in the `arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion()`, not in the `arcpy.env.workspace`.

Your script is attempting to pass a list of values (feature classes or layers?) to the Feature Class to Feature Class tool, however this tool requires a single feature class or layer input.

You either need to loop through the values in this list, something like the following:

```
inputlist = ['roads', 'boundaries', 'trees']
outputfolder = r"c:\temp\geodatabase.gdb"

for fc in inputlist:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(fc, outputfolder, fc)
```

Or use Feature Class to Geodatabase to convert multiple feature classes to a Geodatabase

```
inputlist = ['roads', 'boundaries', 'trees']
outputfolder = r"c:\temp\geodatabase.gdb"

# Execute TableToGeodatabase
arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(inputlist, outputfolder)
```